# Sharedpref data on destroy

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

i have created a project in which i have multiple activities in which i am using sharedpref for each activity,and i am clearing my editors or sharedperf values in on Destroy but its not working for me.I want that my activity should run from activity1 < activity2 < activity3 < activity4 and on back press it works fines from activity4

```
  private void saveData() {
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared_preferenc", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(last_Year_list);
            editor.putString("task_list1", json);
            editor.putString("farmer_id1",farmerID);
            editor.apply();
        }


        private void loadData() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared_preferenc", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task_list1", null);
            farmerID = sharedPreferences.getString("farmer_id1",farmerID);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<last_year_list>>() {
            }.getType();
            last_Year_list = gson.fromJson(json, type);

            if (last_Year_list == null) {
                last_Year_list = new ArrayList<>();
            }else{
                buildRecyclerView();
                linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear1231);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("shared_preferenc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.clear();

        editor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared_preferenc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        preferencesEditor.clear();
        preferencesEditor.apply();


        if (this.mConnReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(this.mConnReceiver);
        }
    }
```

I am using Flag in last activity soo that all previous activit should be destroyed Like:

```
  inms.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // here inms is my Intent
```

Now after completing all process and and trying to enter new data again then its automatically load data from my sharedpref of previous data.

Comment: Instead of clearing the data on OnDestroy why don't you clear it in onCreate() of activity because onDestory will not be called all the times

Comment: if i clear my data in on create then it will  also remove data when i press backbutton to get same state of activity??

Comment: Nope... it will not remove when you press back button

Comment: soo in on create after loading my data in end of on create i should clear the editor value??